# Converting NSString from NSArray into NSDate object using NSDateFormatter gives null in iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string object inside an array that is of the form "2013-06-24 12:57:45".  So what I'm trying to do is convert this string into an NSDate object using NSDateFormatter like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSString *myDate = [myArray objectAtIndex:12];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate];

NSLog(@"%@", date);//this prints out (null)
NSLog(@"%@", myDate);//this prints out the date in the correct format.
```

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I copied your code into my project and it worked just great.  NSLog printed out 2013-06-24 18:57:45 +0000

Comment: Yah, works for me too.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for giving me that feedback.  Not sure why this is.

Comment: Side note - why do you alloc/init an `NSDate` object and then throw the value away?

Comment: I don't know.  How should I be doing this?

Comment: Just do `NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate];`.

Comment: Note that this scheme will fail in the case where someone in a 24-hour local sets their phone to display 12-hour time.

Answer (score 0):

While your code works for me as well, one thing to note is that myDate is actually a string and date is a NSDate. What happens when you do this:

```
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

Comment: In that case, I also get a (null).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who replied.  I found out that the reason why I was getting (null) was that my date value was initially stored as a string surrounded by double quotes.  So in order to fix the problem, I had to remove the quotes from the NSString by doing the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *myDate = [myArray objectAtIndex:12];
NSString *myNewDate = [myDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate];
```

and this gave me my desired output.  Thanks again for all comments and replies.

Answer (score 0):

What's that nonsense?

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate];
```

Do you like creating objects just for fun? What do you think is going to happen with the date that you created with [[NSDate alloc] init] ?

Comment: Can you please explain?